# MySQL: Extract IDs with occurrence between 2 and 10 in a date range

Tags: mysql, date, select, count

I have a table XX with around 25 colums. I just need 4 of them.

I want to extract rows where the ID occur more than one time  - I guess I can do this with count(x) -

The table looks like

```
+------+------++------+------++------+------++------+------++------+------+
ID      Date            T1          T2          T3          .....
+------+------++------+------++------+------++------+------++------+------+
1       2016-01-01      1212        13412       121212
2       2016-01-01      1214        12541       121241
1       2016-01-01      1212        13412       121212
2       2016-01-01      1214        12541       121241
4       2016-01-01      1214        66666       121241
2       2016-01-01      1214        98889       121241
1       2015-01-01      1213        13412       121212
2       2016-01-01      1214        66666       121241
2       2016-01-02      1214        66666       121241
3       2016-01-01      1214        66666       121241
+------+------++------+------++------+------++------+------++------+------+
```

The result should look like this

```
+------+------++------+------++------+------++------+------++------+------+
ID      Date            T1          T2          T3          .....
+------+------++------+------++------+------++------+------++------+------+
1       2016-01-01      1212        13412       121212
2       2016-01-01      1214        12541       121241
2       2016-01-01      1214        12541       121241
2       2016-01-01      1214        98889       121241
2       2016-01-01      1214        66666       121241
2       2016-01-02      1214        66666       121241
+------+------++------+------++------+------++------+------++------+------+
```

As you can see, the result contains IDs with count >1 between a different time date (> 2016-01-01, < NOW).

I tried my select with this query

```
SELECT 
id, id_date, T1, T2, T3
FROM XY
WHERE id IN (
SELECT id
FROM XY
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(*) > 1
) AND date > '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY id, id_date, T1, T2, T3
```

The result is different from an other approach I did. I created first a temporary table with the following query

```
SELECT id, id_date, T1, T2, T3 FROM XY

WHERE id_date > '2016-01-01'

GROUP BY id, id_date, T1, T2, T3
```

Then I took one id out of my temporary table and check the upcoming result with the other approach. They are different.

**Long story short:**

How can I extract IDs with an occurrence between 2 and 10 out of a table between a specific date range? Is there an error in my group by?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (UR #1 Query) WHERE count > 1 and Count < 11 Group by` ?

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY? And where in your query is the '2 and 10' criteria expressed?

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(*) BETWEEN 2 AND 10` - just like you said in the question.

Comment: When you do the counting, you're counting all repetitions, not just repetitions within the date range. If you only want to count repetition in the date range, you need to put the `date` condition in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
id, id_date, T1, T2, T3
FROM XY
WHERE id IN (
SELECT id
FROM XY
where date > 'start-date' and date < 'end-date'
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(*) > 1 and count(*) <11
) AND date > '2016-01-01' 
GROUP BY id, id_date, T1, T2, T3
```

Add in `having` clause another condition for your requirement. add `where` clause to query for extracting ids

Comment: Wow... Thanks a lot. Just a question for the understanding: Why do you use 2 times where for the date? 1. date > '2016-01-01' and 2. date > 'start-date' and date < 'end-date'.

Comment: I picked it up from original query. You can remove it if you don't need it. It doesn't affect extraction of ids